# DurandalJs Plugin Views?

Tags: javascript, jquery, single-page-application, durandal

I am developing an application using DurandalJs, version 1.2.0. I have a unique requirement in that I need to support a plugin view concept. To elaborate, the application should be able to load some views on-demand after being deployed.

This becomes challenging after optimization. When I run the optimizer, everything is merged and "compiled" into one file. I am not sure if it is possible (without too much code) to have something in place that will load views dynamically.

Scenario 1:

- Profile Details View does not exist
- Application Admin uploads a profile details view+viewmodel

Scenario 2:

- Product Details View exists
- App Admin wants to override the existing view functionality
- App Admin uploads a new product details view+viewmodel

Is this possible?

Comment: Don't run the optimizer, then you can do exactly what you are asking.

Comment: We need the optimizer

Comment: The problem is that you will need routes for the dynamic views, so you will have to modify some of the code that is optimized.

Comment: Yup, I understand the challenge. Hence this question.

Comment: Why can't you pull routes dynamically? If the view changes the route will change as well. You can append a version number at the end of each route.

Comment: Yogesh, can you respond with more details of what you mean (and ideally an example)?